# Getting lookup value from Id inside the binding of DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I have a situation where in the below classes will explain

```
public class UserDetail
{
    public string UserCode{get; set;}
    public uint RoleId{get; set;}
    public uint GroupId{get; set;}
}
```

and classes

```
public class UserRoleDetail
{
    public uint RoleId{get; set;}
    public string RoleName{get; set;}
}
```

I have a data grid and bound the datacontext to collection of UserDetail objects.

```
            <DataGrid x:Name="usersgrid"
                      AlternatingRowBackground="LightBlue"
                      CanUserAddRows="False"
                      CanUserDeleteRows="False"
                      CanUserReorderColumns="True"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                      CanUserResizeColumns="True"
                      AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="User Code"
                                        Binding="{Binding Path=UserCode}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Role"
                                        Binding="{Binding Path=RoleId}">
                        <!-- Need to get the RoleName by looking up RoleDetails collection-->
                    </DataGridTextColumn>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Group"
                                        Binding="{Binding Path=GroupId}"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

The output is showing the integer RoleId field in UserDetail class. I want to show it as RoleName by looking up the RoleId in the RoleDetails collection in the code behind.

Is there any way by which i can achieve that in xaml itself. Any light on using converters??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: where are you keeping UserRoleDetail collection? at viewmodel?

Comment: actually these objects are coming from the data layer and due to normalization, the role details were segregated to another class, UserRoleDetail. I will get UserDetails and UserRoleDetails as separate collections. It is available in the Code behind. UserRoleDetailsCollection variable.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion here will be create a wrapper class lets say UserDetailWrapper which contain the UserDetailInstance and UserRoleDetailInstance like this

```
    public class UserDetailWrapper
    {
        public UserDetail UserDetail
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public UserRoleDetail UserRoleDetail { get; set; }
    }
```

in your code behind you generate the list of UserDetailWrapper for UserDetail collection and set the UserRoleDetail correcponding to the roleID.

Now bind this collection as the ItemsSource to the DataGrid.

You will have to update your bindings accordingly like

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="User Code"
                                        Binding="{Binding Path=UserDetail.UserCode}"/>
```

and then for UserRoleDetailName you can directly do

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Role"
                                        Binding="{Binding Path=UserRoleDetail.RoleName}">
```

Comment: I agree to ur answer, but is there any direct methods by which we can achieve this in xaml itself without wrappers. Does Converter come in any help here? I don't have much idea about using converters.

Comment: mate converter will not be helpful here. Think like this, each row of your DataGrid is UserDetail object so if you dont have refernce to UserRoleDetail anywhere in UserDetail how will you get to that. Also even if you use converter that is going to be multivalue converter which will take the RoleId from the UserDetail of row and UserRoleDetails from the VM and will return the RoleName but you will not be able to set the RoleName after that